# Will I be exited from WhatsApp groups when I reset my phone and install app again?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Will I be exited from WhatsApp groups when I reset my phone and install app again? I didn't make backups. Please help it's very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your phone number does not change, your groups will be intact.  But, without backup, your conversation history will be blank.